# avoid update panel trigger by child control

Tags: asp.net, triggers, updatepanel, childcontrol

By default the postback of child controls  will trigger update panels' update.

How can I avoid the same?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `ChildrenAsTriggers` property of the updatepanel to false.

This will stop children causing postbacks by default.

Another way is to look at your scriptmanager's `AsyncPostBackSourceElementID` to identify the control that triggered the event, and then ignore it.

Comment: If this answer helped you, could you mark it as the correct answer by pressing the tick button?